# Perpendicularity in matrix space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $K$ and $Q$ be symmetric real matrices such that $K+Q$ is positive semidefinite ($\ge0$). My question is two questions:

1. Does $KQ=0$ imply $K\ge0$ and $Q\ge0$?
2. Does trace$(KQ)=0$ imply $K\ge0$ and $Q\ge0$?

Comment: About 1): Note that $K^3=K(K+Q)K$ and $Q^3=Q(K+Q)Q$ and RHS are p.s.d.

Comment: @A.G. oh that's neat

Comment: And the eigenvalues of $K^3$ and $Q^3$ are their eigenvalues cubed. Great, thank you.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383895/properties-of-the-cone-of-positive-semidefinite-matrices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1)
From $KQ = 0$ follows that the range of $Q$ is a subspace of the null space of $K$. From symmetry of $K$ and $Q$ follows that also the range of $K$ is a subspace of the null space of $Q$.
Thus, if $u$ is an eigenvector of $K$ to a non zero eigenvalue $\lambda$, we have
$$ (K+Q)u = \lambda u + 0. $$
Similar, the nonzero eigenvalues of $Q$ is also eigenvalues of $K+Q$.
Thus, $K+Q$ is positive semidefinite if and only if $K$ and $Q$ are positive semidefinite.

For 2) let 
$K = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $Q = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.
Then, $K+Q$ is positive semidefinite, $\operatorname{trace}(KQ) = 0$, and $Q$ is not positive semidefinite.

Comment: So if we denote $\langle \cdot\rangle$ the ranges of the matrices, you are saying that in the first case $\langle K\rangle\oplus\langle Q\rangle=\langle K+Q\rangle$ with $\langle K\rangle\perp\langle Q\rangle$?

Comment: @Enredanrestos yes.